# Can a Domain Event return feedback information up to the UI layer?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm still fairly new to DDD applications. I'm reading Eric Evan's "Domain Driven Design" and have read [Employing the Domain Model Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236415.aspx) by [Domain Events Salvation](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) by Udi Dahan...

One thing I can't make out though is how should information about the successful or unsuccesful completion of Domain Events be returned as feedback to the user (i.e. UI Layer)?

For example, we could have the following Application Layer code:

```
// Application Layer
public void SubmitOrder(OrderData data)
{ 
  var customer = GetCustomer(data.CustomerId);
  var shoppingCart = GetShoppingCart(data.CartId);
  customer.Purchase(shoppingCart);
}

// Domain Model
public class Customer
{ 
   public void Purchase(ShoppingCart cart)
   {
      // something done with the cart...

      DomainEvents.Raise(new CustomerPurchaseCompleted() { Customer = this, ShoppingCart = cart });
   }
}
```

Now let's say we have the following event handler that sends a confirmation email to the customer **if** the customer has an email address specified.

```
public class CustomerPurchaseCompletedHandler : Handles<CustomerPurchaseCompleted>
{ 
   public void Handle(CustomerPurchaseCompleted args)
   {
      if (args.Customer.Email != null) {
         // send email to args.Customer
      }
      else {
         // report that no email will be sent...
      }
   }
}
```

**My question is**: How should I "bubble up" a feedback message to the UI layer saying that no email will be sent because the customer doesn't have an email set?

The options as I see them today are along the lines of:

1. Have the UI layer check if the Customer has an email and react accordingly with a message. This seems bad since the UI would be aware that an email is supposed to be sent, which is a application level information.
2. Throw a `UserHasNoEmailException` when no email is present and catch that information somewhere. That's **really bad** because exceptions should not be used to return information, plus it's not a fatal error and should not abort other handlers...
3. Have `SubmitOrder()` return some `List<FeedbackMessage>`. This would require changing the `Purchase()` and `DomainEvents.Raise()` methods to also return this list. This leads to the Domain Model knowing what the UI should of should not display...

Neither of these three options seems really good and practical. So how do DDD experts do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Option 1. It's good because it's supposed to know that "that" is required for the use case to succeed.

Comment: The way I see it is can the use case can succeed in many different variants... just as some errors may not be fatal but still need to be reported back to the user. With Option 1, the UI has to know every possible variant that could happen. Aren't we back back to a big "everything-knows-everything-about-everything-else" application?

Comment: You need to leaarn what real invariants are and stop bothering the end users with things they can't fix. So, no, it's a requirement for the use case to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option you have is to implement another event handler which is specifically responsible for notifying the UI that a customer doesn't have an email address. So where CustomerPurchaseCompletedHandler doesn't send an email, this handler would notify the UI. This handler would be part of the UI layer. A good way to notify the UI would be to inject an [event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) into this handler:

```
public class NotifyingCustomerPurchaseCompletedHandler : Handles<CustomerPurchaseCompleted>
{ 
   public IEventAggregator Events { get; set; }

   public void Handle(CustomerPurchaseCompleted args)
   {
      if (args.Customer.Email == null) {
         // notify UI
         this.Events.GetEvent....
      }
   }
}
```

Overall, this is essentially approach 1. True, the UI layer is now aware that an email is to be sent, however the UI has to have that knowledge regardless because it needs to render a message stating that no email is to be sent. Display a message is a UI concern and by leaving the handler implementation as part of the UI layer you keep it as such. The problem with this approach is that you are checking whether the customer has an email twice. Additionally, the sending of an email is not directly tied to the UI notification.

Another option is to introduce another event to indicate that a purchase was completed for a customer that doesn't have an email. The UI could then subscribe to this event. The downside of this approach is that you are creating an event specifically for a UI requirement not to express domain knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, so before calling `SubmitOrder()`, the UI (ASP.NET MVC) would register it's own Event Handler? This second would probably just set some attribute in the ViewModel to true or false, correct?

I'll try to make sense of the `EventAggregator` link you provided, but I'm not sure I understand how exactly it differs from the Event Registration process...

Comment: The UI specific handler would be registered in the configuration area for the entire app, possibly in the same place that the original `CustomerPurchaseCompletedHandler` is registered. It would not be registered before calling `SubmitOrder()` because that call may happen multiple times during the lifetime of the app and it doesn't make sense to keep registering the handler. The UI specific handler could set an attribute in some ViewModel. The event aggregator I proposed would be a more decoupled way to achieve this - the handler no longer needs to be coupled to a specific ViewModel instance.

Comment: I'm still at a loss as to how this will implement in my app as the domain model layer is deep below the UI layer: ASP.NET MVC --> Web Service API --> App Layer --> Domain Model. But your answer does make sense... :)

Comment: If the MVC project communicates with the domain layer exclusively through a service layer, then the proposed solution won't work. Domain events are meant to be passed within a single process boundary. If the event needs to travel outside of those boundaries, they should be dispatched with some sort of messaging infrastructure. For example, in the service project which encapsulates the domain, implement a handler which forwards with event via [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) all the way to the HTML client.

Answer (score 0):

Events should not report feedback. Events ARE feedback.

In this case the `Email` is a business requirement. So the `customer.Purchase(shoppingCart);` should really throw an exception if the email has not been specified.

But let's say that the actual email delivery fails. What I usually do is to create a domain model which I use for notifications. so I do this:

```
var notification = new Notification(userId, "Failed to deliver receipt to user.");
notificationRepository.Save(noitification);
```

Which in turn would generate a `NotificationCreated` event which can be picked up by the UI.

Comment: I think in this case, an email is not a requirement which is why an exception should not be thrown. There is only a requirement to display a notification in the UI if an email has not been sent instead of halting the entire operation.